# MySql foreign key from the same table (2 columns are relevant to one key)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

New question since I managed to find the answer.

The exercise wants us to create a comments table with reply levels.
there is a post ('id') that has comments ('comment_id') and there is a
comment reply field ('reply_to') that needs to point to an existing comment ('comment_id')  or NULL in case it is a comment to the post itself.
'id' & 'comment_id' are the primary key
'user_id' is a foreign key for a different table
i need a 2nd foreign key which is the reply field ('reply_to')
and on delete of a comment the following comments should be deleted as well.

what I succeeded was setting the foreign key to 'comment_id' but then
if there are many posts with the same comment number it causes chaos.
deleting post #1 comment #1 will result in post #x comment #9 which is a reply
to comment #5 (and not #1) to be deleted as well.

How should I define the key so that only the right comment tree will be 
eliminated?
(description of the db below)

Thanks

Example:
tbl

```
post_id-----comment_id-----reply_to   
   0            0             NULL (to post)
   0            1              0
   1            0              NULL (to post)
   1            1              0
```

wanted action:

```
Delete:       0            0             NULL (to post)
```

wanted result:

```
post_id-----comment_id-----reply_to   
   1            0              NULL (to post)
   1            1              0
```

===========================================================================

## Fixed: needed to add indexing

The exercise wants us to create a comments table with reply levels.
there is a post ('id') that has comments ('comment_id') and there is a
comment reply field ('reply_to') that needs to point to an existing comment ('comment_id')  or NULL in case it is a comment to the post itself.
'id' & 'comment_id' are the primary key
'user_id' is a foreign key for a different table
i need a 2nd foreign key which is the reply field ('reply_to')
and on delete of a comment the following comments should be deleted as well.

I am trying to add a foreign key from the same table but I keep getting
this error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table db.#sql-148f_1027d34' (errno: 150)
```

Here is the definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PostComments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reply_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_counter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`comment_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `PostComments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Posts` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Posts` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`);
```

this is what i am trying to do:

```
ALTER TABLE `PostComments`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ReplyToT`
FOREIGN KEY (`reply_to`)
REFERENCES `PostComments` (`comment_id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

After strolling in a few different threads I tried deleting all of the
entries in this table but still no success.
Also the fields are with the same type (INT)

what else am I possibly missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference two times the same column from the table postcomments with the same id in the table posts:

```
ALTER TABLE `PostComments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Posts` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES  `Posts` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PostComments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`);
```

That has no use.

The first (`id`) in the FOREIGN KEY statement (so FOREIGN KEY **(`id`)**) is the column in the table you are applying the constraint on ( the postcomments table in this case).

So replace the id of your second constraint (of first, does not matter) with the column you actually want to place the constraint on.